# Unable to use object from async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to use the result of my async function. When I print out `result` to console, it works fine, and I get the full object printed to console.

However, when I try to print out `result.data`, it prints `undefined`, even though data is the first object key?

Why am I able to print the output of the async function, but not to reference to its object values?

```
$(document).ready(async function() {
  const date = 20190313;
  const url = 'https://api.jjjacobson.com/dailygames?season=2018-2019-regular&date=' + date;
  let result = await executeCORSRequest(url); //async function
  console.log(result);
  console.log(result.data);
});
```

`console.log(result.data)` returns undefined.

This is the output of `console.log(result)`:

```
{"data":{"lastUpdatedOn":"2019-03-14T05:33:37.759Z","games":[{"schedule":{"id":48584,"startTime":"2019-03-13T23:00:00.000Z","endedTime":null,"awayTeam":{"id":95,"abbreviation":"ORL"},"homeTeam":{"id":94,"abbreviation":"WAS"},"venue":{"id":13,"name":"Capital One Arena"},"venueAllegiance":"HOME","scheduleStatus":"NORMAL","originalStartTime":null,"delayedOrPostponedReason":null,"playedStatus":"COMPLETED","attendance":null,"officials":[],"broadcasters":[],"weather":null},"score":{"currentQuarter":null,"currentQuarterSecondsRemaining":null,"currentIntermission":null,"awayScoreTotal":90,"homeScoreTotal":100,"quarters":[{"quarterNumber":1,"awayScore":28,"homeScore":29},{"quarterNumber":2,"awayScore":25,"homeScore":32},{"quarterNumber":3,"awayScore":21,"homeScore":15},{"quarterNumber":4,"awayScore":16,"homeScore":24}]}},{"schedule":{"id":48586,"startTime":"2019-03-13T23:00:00.000Z","endedTime":null,"awayTeam":{"id":84,"abbreviation":"BRO"},"homeTeam":{"id":96,"abbreviation":"OKL"},"venue":{"id":90,"name":"Chesapeake Energy Arena"},"venueAllegiance":"HOME","scheduleStatus":"NORMAL","originalStartTime":null,"delayedOrPostponedReason":null,"playedStatus":"COMPLETED","attendance":null,"officials":[],"broadcasters":[],"weather":null},"score":{"currentQuarter":null,"currentQuarterSecondsRemaining":null,"currentIntermission":null,"awayScoreTotal":96,"homeScoreTotal":108,"quarters":[{"quarterNumber":1,"awayScore":27,"homeScore":19},{"quarterNumber":2,"awayScore":25,"homeScore":23},{"quarterNumber":3,"awayScore":26,"homeScore":38},{"quarterNumber":4,"awayScore":18,"homeScore":28}]}},{"schedule":{"id":48583,"startTime":"2019-03-13T23:30:00.000Z","endedTime":null,"awayTeam":{"id":88,"abbreviation":"DET"},"homeTeam":{"id":92,"abbreviation":"MIA"},"venue":{"id":86,"name":"American Airlines Arena"},"venueAllegiance":"HOME","scheduleStatus":"NORMAL","originalStartTime":null,"delayedOrPostponedReason":null,"playedStatus":"COMPLETED","attendance":null,"officials":[],"broadcasters":[],"weather":null},"score":{"currentQuarter":null,"currentQuarterSecondsRemaining":null,"currentIntermission":null,"awayScoreTotal":74,"homeScoreTotal":108,"quarters":[{"quarterNumber":1,"awayScore":18,"homeScore":30},{"quarterNumber":2,"awayScore":31,"homeScore":24},{"quarterNumber":3,"awayScore":8,"homeScore":33},{"quarterNumber":4,"awayScore":17,"homeScore":21}]}},{"schedule":{"id":48585,"startTime":"2019-03-13T23:30:00.000Z","endedTime":null,"awayTeam":{"id":107,"abbreviation":"MEM"},"homeTeam":{"id":91,"abbreviation":"ATL"},"venue":{"id":20,"name":"StateFarm Arena"},"venueAllegiance":"HOME","scheduleStatus":"NORMAL","originalStartTime":null,"delayedOrPostponedReason":null,"playedStatus":"COMPLETED","attendance":null,"officials":[],"broadcasters":[],"weather":null},"score":{"currentQuarter":null,"currentQuarterSecondsRemaining":null,"currentIntermission":null,"awayScoreTotal":111,"homeScoreTotal":132,"quarters":[{"quarterNumber":1,"awayScore":28,"homeScore":33},{"quarterNumber":2,"awayScore":32,"homeScore":39},{"quarterNumber":3,"awayScore":30,"homeScore":38},{"quarterNumber":4,"awayScore":21,"homeScore":22}]}},{"schedule":{"id":48587,"startTime":"2019-03-14T01:30:00.000Z","endedTime":null,"awayTeam":{"id":101,"abbreviation":"GSW"},"homeTeam":{"id":109,"abbreviation":"HOU"},"venue":{"id":102,"name":"Toyota Center"},"venueAllegiance":"HOME","scheduleStatus":"NORMAL","originalStartTime":null,"delayedOrPostponedReason":null,"playedStatus":"COMPLETED","attendance":null,"officials":[],"broadcasters":[],"weather":null},"score":{"currentQuarter":null,"currentQuarterSecondsRemaining":null,"currentIntermission":null,"awayScoreTotal":106,"homeScoreTotal":104,"quarters":[{"quarterNumber":1,"awayScore":33,"homeScore":23},{"quarterNumber":2,"awayScore":21,"homeScore":29},{"quarterNumber":3,"awayScore":31,"homeScore":26},{"quarterNumber":4,"awayScore":21,"homeScore":26}]}},{"schedule":{"id":48588,"startTime":"2019-03-14T02:00:00.000Z","endedTime":null,"awayTeam":{"id":98,"abbreviation":"UTA"},"homeTeam":{"id":104,"abbreviation":"PHX"},"venue":{"id":98,"name":"Talking Stick Resort Arena"},"venueAllegiance":"HOME","scheduleStatus":"NORMAL","originalStartTime":null,"delayedOrPostponedReason":null,"playedStatus":"COMPLETED","attendance":null,"officials":[],"broadcasters":[],"weather":null},"score":{"currentQuarter":null,"currentQuarterSecondsRemaining":null,"currentIntermission":null,"awayScoreTotal":114,"homeScoreTotal":97,"quarters":[{"quarterNumber":1,"awayScore":25,"homeScore":27},{"quarterNumber":2,"awayScore":28,"homeScore":16},{"quarterNumber":3,"awayScore":25,"homeScore":32},{"quarterNumber":4,"awayScore":36,"homeScore":22}]}}],"references":{"teamReferences":[{"id":84,"city":"Brooklyn","name":"Nets","abbreviation":"BRO","homeVenue":{"id":78,"name":"Barclays Center"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":88,"city":"Detroit","name":"Pistons","abbreviation":"DET","homeVenue":{"id":145,"name":"Little Caesars Arena"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":91,"city":"Atlanta","name":"Hawks","abbreviation":"ATL","homeVenue":{"id":20,"name":"StateFarm Arena"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":92,"city":"Miami","name":"Heat","abbreviation":"MIA","homeVenue":{"id":86,"name":"American Airlines Arena"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":94,"city":"Washington","name":"Wizards","abbreviation":"WAS","homeVenue":{"id":13,"name":"Capital One Arena"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":95,"city":"Orlando","name":"Magic","abbreviation":"ORL","homeVenue":{"id":89,"name":"Amway Center"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":96,"city":"Oklahoma City","name":"Thunder","abbreviation":"OKL","homeVenue":{"id":90,"name":"Chesapeake Energy Arena"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":98,"city":"Utah","name":"Jazz","abbreviation":"UTA","homeVenue":{"id":92,"name":"Vivint Smart Home Arena"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":101,"city":"Golden State","name":"Warriors","abbreviation":"GSW","homeVenue":{"id":95,"name":"Oracle Arena"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":104,"city":"Phoenix","name":"Suns","abbreviation":"PHX","homeVenue":{"id":98,"name":"Talking Stick Resort Arena"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":107,"city":"Memphis","name":"Grizzlies","abbreviation":"MEM","homeVenue":{"id":100,"name":"FedEx Forum"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null},{"id":109,"city":"Houston","name":"Rockets","abbreviation":"HOU","homeVenue":{"id":102,"name":"Toyota Center"},"teamColoursHex":[],"socialMediaAccounts":[],"officialLogoImageSrc":null}],"venueReferences":[{"id":13,"name":"Capital One Arena","city":"Washington, DC","country":"USA","geoCoordinates":null,"capacitiesByEventType":[],"playingSurface":null,"baseballDimensions":[],"hasRoof":null,"hasRetractableRoof":null},{"id":20,"name":"StateFarm Arena","city":"Atlanta, GA","country":"USA","geoCoordinates":null,"capacitiesByEventType":[],"playingSurface":null,"baseballDimensions":[],"hasRoof":null,"hasRetractableRoof":null},{"id":86,"name":"American Airlines Arena","city":"Miami, FL","country":"USA","geoCoordinates":null,"capacitiesByEventType":[],"playingSurface":null,"baseballDimensions":[],"hasRoof":null,"hasRetractableRoof":null},{"id":90,"name":"Chesapeake Energy Arena","city":"Oklahama City, OK","country":"USA","geoCoordinates":null,"capacitiesByEventType":[],"playingSurface":null,"baseballDimensions":[],"hasRoof":null,"hasRetractableRoof":null},{"id":98,"name":"Talking Stick Resort Arena","city":"Phoenix, AZ","country":"USA","geoCoordinates":null,"capacitiesByEventType":[],"playingSurface":null,"baseballDimensions":[],"hasRoof":null,"hasRetractableRoof":null},{"id":102,"name":"Toyota Center","city":"Houston, TX","country":"USA","geoCoordinates":null,"capacitiesByEventType":[],"playingSurface":null,"baseballDimensions":[],"hasRoof":null,"hasRetractableRoof":null}]}}}
```

Comment: try using `JSON.parse(result)`. It could be that it is returning a string, and as such it does not contain the field `data`.

Comment: what do you get if you put `console.log(typeof result);`? If string, it means the answer is in JSON.

Comment: @MatthewVarga that was it! thanks

Comment: try `console.log(result[0].data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the `result` is a string you have to parse it using `JSON.parse()` :

```
let obj = JSON.parse(result);
```

Later

```
console.log(obj.data)
```